# How to toggle list sublist sublist ... with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am basically a PHP developer and am stuck on jQuery. I was able to display all the files of my directory in the form of lists on the page. I want to do toggle effect on them like when we click on the folder it slides all the files which are in them. But these are dynamic and could be hundreds in each folder. Heres what I made [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2eZVk). I have pasted HTML version of my code to this fiddle. 
jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.directory').find('ul').hide();

    $('.directory').click(function (e) {
        $(this).children().show('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: webservers has file explorers built in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $(".directory").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').toggle('fast');
  });
});
```

this will do the trick :)

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/fumec/2/edit)

Comment: Sorry man. Your wrong check out styles directory. Its not correct.

Comment: hey what is the function of :first?

Comment: It's a typo , it should be first-child. It detects only the first ul sub menu not the children's ul..